# overloading << operator on enums gives runtime error

Tags: c++, enums

Like in this code :

```
#include <iostream>

enum class A {
    a,
    b
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, A val)
{
        return os << val;
}


int main() {
    auto a = A::a;
    std::cout << a;
    return 0;
}
```

When I did not provide `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, A val)` the program didn't compile because A::a didn't have any function to go with `<<`. But now when I've already provided it, it produces garbage in my terminal and on [ideone](http://ideone.com/X6iOqH), it produces a runtime error (time limit exceeded).

Comment: `static_cast<type>(val)`

Comment: Recommend spending some time learning your development environment's debugger. You would have seen what was going wrong within a few steps and saved yourself some time. Other than that, a very well-posed question. Wish we saw more reduced to this tight an MCVE.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, A val) {
    return os << val;
}
```

This causes infinite recursion. Remember that `os << val` is really seen to the compiler `operator<<(os,val)` in this instance. What you want to do is print the underlying value of the enum. Fortunately, there is a type_trait that allows you to expose the underlying type of the enum and then you can cast the parameter to that type and print it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

enum class A {
    a, b
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, A val) {
    return os << static_cast<std::underlying_type<A>::type>(val);
}

int main() {
    auto a = A::a;
    std::cout << a;
}
```

Comment: just one question to ask - is this pure compile time method or some run time introspection is required for determining the underlying type

Comment: This is pure compile time.

Answer (score 5):

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, A val)
{
   return os << val; // Calls the function again.
                     // Results in infinite recursion.
}
```

Try

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, A val)
{
   return os << static_cast<int>(val);

}
```